# How can I get the value displayed by a labeled animator control to read in degrees?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I have thus far:

```
DynamicModule[{g = 9.8, v0 = 100},
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   ParametricPlot[{(v0 Cos[α]) t, (v0 Sin[α]) t - 
      g t^2/2},
    {t, 0, thit},
    PlotRange -> {{-0.10 xhit, 
       1.20 xhit}, {1.10 (-Tan[θ] (1.10 xhit)), 
       1.10 (v0^2 Sin[α]^2/(2 g))}}],
   Plot[Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {-Tan[θ] x, 
       0 <= x < 1.10 xhit}, {-Tan[θ] (1.10 xhit), 
       x >= 1.10 xhit}}], {x, xspan[[1]], xspan[[2]]},
    PlotRange -> {{-0.10 xhit, 
       1.20 xhit}, {1.10 (-Tan[θ] (1.10 xhit)), 
       1.10 (v0^2 Sin[α]^2/(2 g))}},
    Filling -> Bottom],
   Graphics[{
     Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, v0 {Cos[α], Sin[α]}}],
     Text[
      Style["Range = " <> ToString[Round[range, .1]], Black, 
       Background -> White], 0.5 {xhit, yhit}]
     }]
   ],
  {{α, 58 Degree}, 10 Degree, 70 Degree, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{θ, 30 Degree}, 10 Degree, 40 Degree, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{xspan, xspan}, None},
  {{xhit, xhit}, None},
  {{thit, thit}, None},
  {{yhit, yhit}, None},
  {{range, range}, None},
  Initialization :> (
    thit := 2 v0 Cos[α]/g*(Tan[α] + Tan[θ]);
    xhit := 2 v0^2 Cos[α]^2/g*(Tan[α] + Tan[θ]);
    yhit := 
     2 v0^2 Cos[α]^2/
       g*(Tan[α] + Tan[θ])*(-Tan[θ]);
    xspan := {-0.10 xhit, 1.20 xhit};
    range := 
     2 v0^2 Cos[α] Sin[α + θ]/(g Cos[θ]^2);
    )
  ]
 ]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

However, as I begin moving the sliders the appearance labels are changed to radian. How can I make them be labeled as degrees.

**Update thanks to Karsten 7**

Kirsten 7's comment works perfectly.

```
DynamicModule[{g = 9.8, v0 = 100},
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   ParametricPlot[{(v0 Cos[\[Alpha]]) t, (v0 Sin[\[Alpha]]) t - 
      g t^2/2},
    {t, 0, thit},
    PlotRange -> {{-0.10 xhit, 
       1.20 xhit}, {1.10 (-Tan[\[Theta]] (1.10 xhit)), 
       1.10 (v0^2 Sin[\[Alpha]]^2/(2 g))}}],
   Plot[Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {-Tan[\[Theta]] x, 
       0 <= x < 1.10 xhit}, {-Tan[\[Theta]] (1.10 xhit), 
       x >= 1.10 xhit}}], {x, xspan[[1]], xspan[[2]]},
    PlotRange -> {{-0.10 xhit, 
       1.20 xhit}, {1.10 (-Tan[\[Theta]] (1.10 xhit)), 
       1.10 (v0^2 Sin[\[Alpha]]^2/(2 g))}},
    Filling -> Bottom],
   Graphics[{
     Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, v0 {Cos[\[Alpha]], Sin[\[Alpha]]}}],
     Text[
      Style["Range = " <> ToString[Round[range, .1]], Black, 
       Background -> White], 0.5 {xhit, yhit}]
     }]
   ],
  Row[{Control[{{\[Alpha], 58 Degree}, 10 Degree, 70 Degree}], 
    Spacer[10], Dynamic[\[Alpha]/Degree], "\[Degree]"}],
  Row[{Control[{{\[Theta], 30 Degree}, 10 Degree, 40 Degree}], 
    Spacer[10], Dynamic[\[Theta]/Degree], "\[Degree]"}],
  {{xspan, xspan}, None},
  {{xhit, xhit}, None},
  {{thit, thit}, None},
  {{yhit, yhit}, None},
  {{range, range}, None},
  Initialization :> (
    thit := 2 v0 Cos[\[Alpha]]/g*(Tan[\[Alpha]] + Tan[\[Theta]]);
    xhit := 2 v0^2 Cos[\[Alpha]]^2/g*(Tan[\[Alpha]] + Tan[\[Theta]]);
    yhit := 
     2 v0^2 Cos[\[Alpha]]^2/
       g*(Tan[\[Alpha]] + Tan[\[Theta]])*(-Tan[\[Theta]]);
    xspan := {-0.10 xhit, 1.20 xhit};
    range := 
     2 v0^2 Cos[\[Alpha]] Sin[\[Alpha] + \[Theta]]/(g Cos[\[Theta]]^2);
    )
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following much simpler `Manipulate` shows one way, how to get a label in `Degree`, while the variable value is in radian.

```
Manipulate[x, 
 Row[{Control[{{x, 0 Degree}, 0 Degree, 100 Degree}], Spacer[10], 
   Dynamic[x/Degree], "\[Degree]"}]]
```

> [image: ManipulateGIF]

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly. See my update to my original post. Thanks.